# Is this a bug of findbugs?

Tags: maven, jenkins, findbugs

I have a jenkins plugin which contains code like this:

```
public int getLastBuildNumber() {
    if (project != null && project.getLastBuild() != null ) {
        return project.getLastBuild().getNumber();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I publish the code with `mvn release:prepare release:perform -Dusername=myusername -Dpassword=mypassword`, I got a bug saying `Possible null pointer dereference`.

Here's the result of `mvn findbugs:gui`:

[image]

Why does it say `The return value from a method is dereferenced without a null check`?

I think `project != null && project.getLastBuild() != null` is the null check, isn't it?

Is this a bug of findbugs? How can I solve it? Or can I disable findbugs when releasing my jenkins plugin?

You can visit [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/display-console-output-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/displayconsoleoutput/DisplayConsoleOutputAction.java) for the full code.

Comment: Moving this question to **meta**.stackexchange.com... Sorry, just kidding!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your `Project` class is immutable or (at least) the value returned by `getLastBuild()` is a `final` field, your null-checks are not enough.

That's because, in theory, some other thread may call `project.setLastBuild(null)` just before your `return` statement:

```
if (project != null && project.getLastBuild() != null) {
    // thread T does project.setLastBuild(null) here -- for whatever reason
    return project.getLastBuild().getNumber(); // NPE!
}
```

To make this bullet proof, you need to move away from those moving parts and make your own local copies (synchronization is hardly an option in this case, imho):

```
LastBuild lastBuild = project != null ? project.getLastBuild() : null; // this only works as long as your project reference is final
return lastBuild != null ? lastBuild.getNumber() : 0;
```

Or, even better, make use of the Java8 `Optional` to perform all the necessary null-checks (implicitly) in one go:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(project)
    .map(Project::getLastBuild)
    .map(LastBuild::getNumber)
    .orElse(0);
```